# Purpose of class ExplicitInit in objc runtime source code

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm studying `class ExplicitInit` in objc runtime source code. I know that class ExplicitInit is used in `static objc::ExplicitInit<StripedMap<SideTable>> SideTablesMap;`. But why ExplicitInit is necessary? StripedMap is good enough to store SideTable.

I think the comments for `class ExplicitInit` in DenseMapExtras.h is the key to understand why ExplicitInit is necessary. But I can't understand the comments because of my poor C++ knowledge.
the comments show below:

```
// We cannot use a C++ static initializer to initialize certain globals because
// libc calls us before our C++ initializers run. We also don't want a global
// pointer to some globals because of the extra indirection.
//
// ExplicitInit / LazyInit wrap doing it the hard way.
```

there are three sentences in comments above, but I can't understand them all. Can anybody help me explain them?

And don't forget the first question: why ExplicitInit is necessary?

Comment: Just in terms of the language. It seems some init needs to run for this (X?) to work. The usual approach is to use a static init or variable, but here it does not work as it is called too late - after X is called. So X needs to perform the init here. One way of doing so is to use a global pointer variable but that is not a *neat* way of doing things so rather X takes care of it here inside this ExplicitInit. Make sense?

Comment: I'm not forgetting first question - why necessary. For that I need to look at the code a bit more deeply so I took the easy way and just explained how I understand the comment. So I don't know anything about X!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We cannot use a C++ static initializer to initialize certain globals because libc calls us before our C++ initializers run.

There is some deep dyld and Mach-O voodoo that I don't understand when it comes to the Objective-C runtime! This was a fun question to try dig into.

The function `_objc_init()` (in `objc-os.mm`) performs:

> Bootstrap initialization. Registers our image notifier with dyld.
> Called by libSystem BEFORE library initialization time

`_objc_init()` calls `runtime_init()`, a portion of which is `objc::allocatedClasses.init();`. `allocatedClasses` is declared as `static ExplicitInitDenseSet<Class> allocatedClasses;` in `objc-runtime-new.mm`.

So it appears `libSystem` calls `_objc_init()` which in turns calls `runtime_init()` which in turn uses a C++ static variable that hasn't yet been constructed because the library itself hasn't been initialized, hence the need for `ExplicitInit`.

> We also don't want a global pointer to some globals because of the extra indirection.

I don't know why this design wasn't chosen. Perhaps for cache locality?

> ExplicitInit / LazyInit wrap doing it the hard way.

The `init()` methods in these classes use placement new to explicitly initialize the underlying type into the space reserved for it in `_storage`. This would normally happen automatically during static initialization if the type was instantiated directly. In this case space is reserved for the underlying object so it may be explicitly initialized by calling `init()` which constructs the object.

Comment: I have read your answer five times probably. Thank you for your inspiration, I think I have got the reason.

Comment: The section ["Solving The Static Initialization Order Fiasco" of this article](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2020/01/02/static-variable-initialization/#the-red-zone---static-initialization-order-fiasco), explains why "We cannot use a C++ static initializer to initialize certain globals because libc calls us before our C++ initializers run.". `ExplicitInit` is not necessary for this situation.

I think the meaning of `ExplicitInit` and `LazyInit` in objc is that the objc developer want to tell us the design pattern: Explicit and Lazy.

Comment: That article is written from a C++-only context so while the static init order fiasco is valid, since the ObjC runtime library is called by libc before the C++ static initializers are run, `ExplicitInit` is needed to make sure the objects are constructed before they are used.